# Read Json in Pyspark

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I want to read a JSON file in PySpark, but the JSON file is in this format (without comma and square brackets):

```
{"id": 1, "name": "jhon"}
{"id": 2, "name": "bryan"}
{"id": 3, "name": "jane"}
```

Is there an easy way to read this JSON in PySpark?

I have already tried this code:

```
df= spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("data.json")
df.write.parquet("data.parquet")
```

But it doesn't work: in parquet file just the first line appears.

I just want to read this JSON file and save as parquet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first line appears while reading data from your mentioned file because of `multiline` parameter is set as `True` but in this case one line is a JSON object. So if you set `multiline` parameter as `False` it will work as expected.

```
df= spark.read.option("multiline", "false").json("data.json")
df.show()
```

In case if your JSON file would have had a JSON array in file like

```
[
{"id": 1, "name": "jhon"},
{"id": 2, "name": "bryan"},
{"id": 3, "name": "jane"}
]
```

or

```
[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "jhon"
    },
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "bryan"
    }
]
```

`multiline` parameter set to `True` will work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, here worked properly!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to read as a text file first, and parse it to a json object

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
import json

lines = spark.read.text("data.json")
parsed_lines = lines.rdd.map(lambda row: json.loads(row[0]))

# Convert JSON objects --> a DataFrame
df = parsed_lines.toDF()
df.write.parquet("data.parquet")
```